# CSS Rel not working in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, rel

I'v tried adding some css specific for the rel attribute, and demoing it in chrome. Example:

```
pre[rel="js"]:before {
   content:"JavaScript";
}

pre[rel="css"]:before {
   content:"CSS";
}
```

Then of course adding HTML to it. In chrome, it all turns out to have "JavaScript" before, ignoring the rest of the CSS, although on Firefox it work's just fine.

[The page I did this on](http://www.schart.net/-%20New%20Folder/CODE%20BOX%202.html).

Comment: Not that this should affect CSS rendering, but it's not valid to have a `rel` attribute on `<pre>` elements. What version of Chrome are you on?

Comment: What's the problem?  It seems to work fine in Google Chrome.

Comment: Works for me on Chrome 16. What version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huh. That's really weird. Definitely a Chrome bug.

I can reproduce your problem reliably in Chrome 16.0.912.63

Adding

```
pre[rel] {
  font-size:1em;
}
```

to the stylesheet clears the problem, but the clause seems to need to contain at least one valid style.

There's no reason I can think of why this should be intended behaviour.

Note that had you used a class instead of the invalid use of the rel attribute, the problem would not have occurred. e.g. Use

```
<pre class="js code">
```

and

```
pre.js:before {
    content:"JavaScript";
    padding-right:434px;
}
```

etc.

Comment: Thank's! Simply adding the "font-size:1em;" thingy, fixed the whole thing, have absolutely no idea why. But thank's man. And thumbs up or somewhat of a system to reward you :)?